# Looking for an algorithm to track rats

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab

I have a seemingly simple problem but I just can't figure it out
I have a logical array: 00001100001111100000
I call a consectuive set of zeros as a gap and a set of ones as a segment.

I want to do 2 things with this:
the first one is to fix the array so that whenever there is a gap with fewer elements than a min_gap=5, change the values to ones, meaning if the gap is too short, then absorbe it into the previouse segment.

similarly, the minimal segment length is min_seg =2, so if a segment is too short, change the values of the array to zeros and combine it with the pervieus gap UNLESS there is another segment up ahead with a gap that has fewer elements than min_gap.

0000011100111 should be converted to 00000111**11**111 the gap was eliminated

0000010000011 should be converted to 00000**0**0000011 the short segment was eliminated

0000010101111 should be converted to 000001**1**1**1**1111 here, insead of erasing the first short segment, it remained and was combined with the next segment

The next task is to identify the starting and ending points of each segment

for 00000110000011110000 the output should be: startingPoints = [6,13], enddingPoints = [7,16]

Please help, I'm stuck on this the whole day.
The code can be in different languges, I just need to see the logic

Some contexts,
I'm tracking a rat's movement and it's proximaty to a stimulus (another rat or an object), and I want to get the timepoint of when the rat was interacting with the stimulus.
So I have a list of video frames of when the rats head was close to the stimulus and when it was far away, but sometimes the rat moves away for less than half a second (min_gap) and comes back, I want to consider this as a single continues interaction unless it moves away for a long time.

Comment: What would be an expected output of `...000110011000...`? Do you want to eliminate the short segments, or a short gap between them?

Comment: always prioritize the segments, in this case, the output should be ....000111111000...
In this specific example, there is no debate, the segments are valid since they have suficiant length (min_seg = 2), but even if the segments were shorter, the outout should keep them
 ...00010011000... - > ...00011111000...

Comment: What about the beginning of the string? Should `00111...` be converted to `11111` or left as is?

Comment: @beaker The first 2 00 should remain 00, I just padd the beginning and the end with zeros with the length of min_gap-1 to make sure that the first zeros dont get eliminated

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi please accept my apologies, I usually mannage to solve these problems alone but as I said I tried for a long time, written and rewritten code that didn't work and it would be unbeneficed to post my poor atempts. in any case, I will remmeber your comment for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems quite simple indeed. Just don't cramp everything into the single function. There are three steps, which correspond to three functions:

1. Eliminate gaps
2. Eliminate segments
3. Identify segments

For example,

```
    eliminate_gaps
        gap_end = 0
        while ((gap_start = find_first(gap_end, 0)) != end_of_string)
            gap_end = find_first(gap_start, 1)
            if (gap_end - gap_start < min_gap)
                fill(gap_start, gap_end, 1)

    eliminate_segments
        segment_end = 0
        while ((segment_start = find_first(segment_end, 1)) != end_of_string)
            segment_end = find_first(segment_start, 0)
            if (segment_end - segment_start < min_segment)
                fill(segment_start, segment_end, 0)
```

These two look suspiciously similar, and may benefit from a helper:

```
    eliminate_runs(kind, min_length)
        run_end = 0
        while ((run_start = find_first(run_end, kind)) != end_of_string)
            run_end = find_first(run_start, ~kind)
            if (run_end - run_start < min_length)
                fill(run_start, run_end, ~kind)

    eliminate_gaps
        eliminate_runs(0, min_gap)

    eliminate_segments
        eliminate_runs(1, min_segment)
```

`find_first`, `fill` and `identify` are left as an exercise.